# how to make a list of icons in flutter, dart?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm new to Android Studio and Flutter.
I'm trying to make a list of icons that I can iterate into a ListView.

I receive this error:
`The element type 'IconData' can't be assigned to the list type 'Icon'.`

For doing this:

```
   static const _iconTypes = <Icon>[
   Icons.cake,
   Icons.add_location_sharp,
   Icons.zoom_in_outlined,
   Icons.auto_awesome_motion,
   Icons.call_end_sharp,
   Icons.equalizer_rounded,
   Icons.wifi_lock,
   Icons.mail,
  ];
```

Is `<icon>` an incorrect datatype to use here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `IconData`

```
  static const _iconTypes = <IconData>[
    Icons.cake,
    Icons.add_location_sharp,
    Icons.zoom_in_outlined,
    Icons.auto_awesome_motion,
    Icons.call_end_sharp,
    Icons.equalizer_rounded,
    Icons.wifi_lock,
    Icons.mail,
  ];
```

And you can use it like

```
    ...
     Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: _iconTypes.map((icon) => Icon(icon)).toList(),
      ),
    )
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

**Do this instead:**

```
List<IconData> _iconTypes = [ 
 Icons.cake,
 Icons.add_location_sharp,
 Icons.zoom_in_outlined,
 Icons.auto_awesome_motion,
 Icons.call_end_sharp,
 Icons.equalizer_rounded,
 Icons.wifi_lock,
 Icons.mail,
];
```

If this still doesn't work please include your `ListView` also in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final  List<IconData> icons = [
    Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied,
    Icons.home,
    Icons.drafts,
    Icons.backspace
];
```

I hope You can easily use this in your widgets.